# Как работать с QIWI API на Python?

Tags: python-3.x, qiwi

Надеюсь, на таком большом сервисе есть русскоязычная аудитория, которая уже разобралась с такой проблемой.

В целом, мне нужно, что бы меня логинило на сайте Qiwi, и после запроса был просмотр платежей и комментариев к платежам. Ну и возврата если комментарий найден "1" если нет "0".

Если есть готовые примеры, библиотеки, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: https://developer.qiwi.com/qiwiwallet/qiwicom_ru.html

Comment: Заходишь на такой известный сайт [github](https://github.com) и в поиске вводишь 'qiwi python'. Примеры: [pyqiwi](https://github.com/onrik/pyqiwi), [pyqiwiapi](https://github.com/Fomchenkov/pyqiwiapi)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Одна проблема, они не работают коректно.

Comment: Все очень корректно работает. незабывайте создать токен в личном кабинете киви!!

Answer (score 3):

Лучше не пользоваться сторонними модулями Python для работы с QIWI Кошельком.
Можно остаться без денег на своем балансе.

Обновленный API стал проще, с помощью стандартной питоновской библиотеки requests можно, например, получить историю последних 10 платежей.

```
import requests
import json

api_access_token = '' # токен можно получить здесь https://qiwi.com/api
my_login = '' # номер QIWI Кошелька в формате +79991112233

s = requests.Session()
s.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + api_access_token  
parameters = {'rows': '10'}
h = s.get('https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v1/persons/'+my_login+'/payments', params = parameters)
print(json.loads(h.text))
```

Остальные запросы (профиль пользователя, балансы, отправка платежей и переводов) делаются по аналогии. [Подробнее можно почитать в документации](https://developer.qiwi.com/qiwiwallet/qiwicom_ru.html)

Comment: Может и «проще», но правильным с точки зрения структуры, как мне кажется, он не станет никогда ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯