# QIWI API в Telegram-боте

Tags: php, python, telegram-bot, qiwi

Хочу сделать оплату цифрового товара через Telegram-бота на QIWI.
Проблема в том, что не знаю, как это правильно реализовать + нет нормальной библиотеки для работы с API QIWI. Можете подсказать примеры оплаты? Предпочтительней на PHP, но можно и на Python.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий, не понятно, с чем возникла проблема. Для работы с API QIWI-кошелька вам достаточно возможности отправлять HTTP-запросы. Для этого используются cURL в PHP и requests в Python. Надеюсь вы уже ознакомились с [документацией](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwicom/index.html). Впрочем, возможна более тесная интеграция платёжных сервисов [средствами Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#how-do-you-process-payments). Правда, QIWI в таком случае не поддерживается.

Comment: @mymedia вот например вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699765/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-qiwi-api-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python
Это получение списка последних платежей, а как реализовать оплату? Хотелось бы увидеть пример на PHP, если можно. Буду Вам очень признателен!

Comment: к хакатону готовитесь?

Comment: @Anatol нет, делаю своего бота для покупки цифровых товаров (тексты и прочее), не получается реализовать подключение к QIWI

Comment: Я не помню, как именно это делается, но для использования QIWI не обязателен какой-либо API. Я помню, проверял на PHP и отправлял запрос с токеном, получая на выходе вроде JSON ответ.

Comment: извините хотел сказать не обязательны библиотеки КИВИ можно через АПИ подключится без специальных либ

Comment: телеграм в вопросе про апи киви неуместен. апи на то и апи, чтоб работать везде одинаково

Answer (score -1):

```
from glQiwiApi import QiwiWrapper, types as qiwi_types
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).